# How do I show this in a message box?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to show `"30%"` in a `MessageBox`.
How can I get this information from an element in a `WebBrowser`?

```
id="meterNumber">30%<
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [HtmlDocument.GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
MsgBox(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("meterNumber").InnerText)
```